# CX_Freeze executable gives "unable to load file system codec" error

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-3.5, cx-freeze

I'm trying to get a hello world program to work with cx_freeze.  It's building fine but I get errors when I run the exe:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

My python script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello World.')
```

And my cx_freeze setup file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe = Executable(
    script="py_helloWorld.py"
    )

setup( name = "helloWorld",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Hello World on command prompt .exe from cx_freeze",
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

When I run:

```
py cx_setup.py build
```

I get:

```
running build
running build_exe
copying C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> build\exe.win32-3.5\py_helloWorld.exe
copying C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\Scripts\python35.dll -> build\exe.win32-3.5\python35.dll
*** WARNING *** unable to create version resource
install pywin32 extensions first
writing zip file build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\python35.zip

  Name                      File
  ----                      ----
m BUILD_CONSTANTS
m __future__                C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\__future__.py
m __startup__               C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py
m _ast
m _bootlocale               C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\_bootlocale.py
m _bz2                      C:\Python35\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
m _codecs
m _codecs_cn
m _codecs_hk
m _codecs_iso2022
m _codecs_jp
m _codecs_kr
m _codecs_tw
m _collections
m _collections_abc          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\_collections_abc.py
m _compression              C:\Python35\Lib\_compression.py
m _datetime
m _dummy_thread             C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\_dummy_thread.py
m _functools
m _hashlib                  C:\Python35\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
m _heapq
m _imp
m _io
m _locale
m _lzma                     C:\Python35\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
m _md5
m _multibytecodec
m _opcode
m _operator
m _random
m _sha1
m _sha256
m _sha512
m _signal
m _socket                   C:\Python35\DLLs\_socket.pyd
m _sre
m _ssl                      C:\Python35\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
m _stat
m _string
m _strptime                 C:\Python35\Lib\_strptime.py
m _struct
m _thread
m _threading_local          C:\Python35\Lib\_threading_local.py
m _warnings
m _weakref
m _weakrefset               C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\_weakrefset.py
m _winapi
m abc                       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\abc.py
m argparse                  C:\Python35\Lib\argparse.py
m ast                       C:\Python35\Lib\ast.py
m atexit
m base64                    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\base64.py
m bdb                       C:\Python35\Lib\bdb.py
m binascii
m builtins
m bz2                       C:\Python35\Lib\bz2.py
m calendar                  C:\Python35\Lib\calendar.py
m cmd                       C:\Python35\Lib\cmd.py
m code                      C:\Python35\Lib\code.py
m codecs                    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\codecs.py
m codeop                    C:\Python35\Lib\codeop.py
P collections               C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\collections\__init__.py
m collections.abc           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\collections\abc.py
m contextlib                C:\Python35\Lib\contextlib.py
m copy                      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\copy.py
m copyreg                   C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\copyreg.py
m datetime                  C:\Python35\Lib\datetime.py
m difflib                   C:\Python35\Lib\difflib.py
m dis                       C:\Python35\Lib\dis.py
m doctest                   C:\Python35\Lib\doctest.py
m dummy_threading           C:\Python35\Lib\dummy_threading.py
P email                     C:\Python35\Lib\email\__init__.py
m email._encoded_words      C:\Python35\Lib\email\_encoded_words.py
m email._header_value_parser C:\Python35\Lib\email\_header_value_parser.py
m email._parseaddr          C:\Python35\Lib\email\_parseaddr.py
m email._policybase         C:\Python35\Lib\email\_policybase.py
m email.base64mime          C:\Python35\Lib\email\base64mime.py
m email.charset             C:\Python35\Lib\email\charset.py
m email.contentmanager      C:\Python35\Lib\email\contentmanager.py
m email.encoders            C:\Python35\Lib\email\encoders.py
m email.errors              C:\Python35\Lib\email\errors.py
m email.feedparser          C:\Python35\Lib\email\feedparser.py
m email.generator           C:\Python35\Lib\email\generator.py
m email.header              C:\Python35\Lib\email\header.py
m email.headerregistry      C:\Python35\Lib\email\headerregistry.py
m email.iterators           C:\Python35\Lib\email\iterators.py
m email.message             C:\Python35\Lib\email\message.py
m email.parser              C:\Python35\Lib\email\parser.py
m email.policy              C:\Python35\Lib\email\policy.py
m email.quoprimime          C:\Python35\Lib\email\quoprimime.py
m email.utils               C:\Python35\Lib\email\utils.py
P encodings                 C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\__init__.py
m encodings.aliases         C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\aliases.py
m encodings.ascii           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\ascii.py
m encodings.base64_codec    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\base64_codec.py
m encodings.big5            C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\big5.py
m encodings.big5hkscs       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\big5hkscs.py
m encodings.bz2_codec       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\bz2_codec.py
m encodings.charmap         C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\charmap.py
m encodings.cp037           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp037.py
m encodings.cp1006          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1006.py
m encodings.cp1026          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1026.py
m encodings.cp1125          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1125.py
m encodings.cp1140          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1140.py
m encodings.cp1250          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1250.py
m encodings.cp1251          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1251.py
m encodings.cp1252          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1252.py
m encodings.cp1253          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1253.py
m encodings.cp1254          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1254.py
m encodings.cp1255          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1255.py
m encodings.cp1256          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1256.py
m encodings.cp1257          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1257.py
m encodings.cp1258          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp1258.py
m encodings.cp273           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp273.py
m encodings.cp424           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp424.py
m encodings.cp437           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp437.py
m encodings.cp500           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp500.py
m encodings.cp65001         C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp65001.py
m encodings.cp720           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp720.py
m encodings.cp737           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp737.py
m encodings.cp775           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp775.py
m encodings.cp850           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp850.py
m encodings.cp852           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp852.py
m encodings.cp855           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp855.py
m encodings.cp856           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp856.py
m encodings.cp857           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp857.py
m encodings.cp858           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp858.py
m encodings.cp860           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp860.py
m encodings.cp861           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp861.py
m encodings.cp862           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp862.py
m encodings.cp863           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp863.py
m encodings.cp864           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp864.py
m encodings.cp865           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp865.py
m encodings.cp866           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp866.py
m encodings.cp869           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp869.py
m encodings.cp874           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp874.py
m encodings.cp875           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp875.py
m encodings.cp932           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp932.py
m encodings.cp949           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp949.py
m encodings.cp950           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\cp950.py
m encodings.euc_jis_2004    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\euc_jis_2004.py
m encodings.euc_jisx0213    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\euc_jisx0213.py
m encodings.euc_jp          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\euc_jp.py
m encodings.euc_kr          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\euc_kr.py
m encodings.gb18030         C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\gb18030.py
m encodings.gb2312          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\gb2312.py
m encodings.gbk             C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\gbk.py
m encodings.hex_codec       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\hex_codec.py
m encodings.hp_roman8       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\hp_roman8.py
m encodings.hz              C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\hz.py
m encodings.idna            C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\idna.py
m encodings.iso2022_jp      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp.py
m encodings.iso2022_jp_1    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_1.py
m encodings.iso2022_jp_2    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_2.py
m encodings.iso2022_jp_2004 C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_2004.py
m encodings.iso2022_jp_3    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_3.py
m encodings.iso2022_jp_ext  C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_ext.py
m encodings.iso2022_kr      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso2022_kr.py
m encodings.iso8859_1       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_1.py
m encodings.iso8859_10      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_10.py
m encodings.iso8859_11      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_11.py
m encodings.iso8859_13      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_13.py
m encodings.iso8859_14      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_14.py
m encodings.iso8859_15      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_15.py
m encodings.iso8859_16      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_16.py
m encodings.iso8859_2       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_2.py
m encodings.iso8859_3       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_3.py
m encodings.iso8859_4       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_4.py
m encodings.iso8859_5       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_5.py
m encodings.iso8859_6       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_6.py
m encodings.iso8859_7       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_7.py
m encodings.iso8859_8       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_8.py
m encodings.iso8859_9       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\iso8859_9.py
m encodings.johab           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\johab.py
m encodings.koi8_r          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\koi8_r.py
m encodings.koi8_t          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\koi8_t.py
m encodings.koi8_u          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\koi8_u.py
m encodings.kz1048          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\kz1048.py
m encodings.latin_1         C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\latin_1.py
m encodings.mac_arabic      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_arabic.py
m encodings.mac_centeuro    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_centeuro.py
m encodings.mac_croatian    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_croatian.py
m encodings.mac_cyrillic    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_cyrillic.py
m encodings.mac_farsi       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_farsi.py
m encodings.mac_greek       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_greek.py
m encodings.mac_iceland     C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_iceland.py
m encodings.mac_latin2      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_latin2.py
m encodings.mac_roman       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_roman.py
m encodings.mac_romanian    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_romanian.py
m encodings.mac_turkish     C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mac_turkish.py
m encodings.mbcs            C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\mbcs.py
m encodings.palmos          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\palmos.py
m encodings.ptcp154         C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\ptcp154.py
m encodings.punycode        C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\punycode.py
m encodings.quopri_codec    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\quopri_codec.py
m encodings.raw_unicode_escape C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\raw_unicode_escape.py
m encodings.rot_13          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\rot_13.py
m encodings.shift_jis       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\shift_jis.py
m encodings.shift_jis_2004  C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\shift_jis_2004.py
m encodings.shift_jisx0213  C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\shift_jisx0213.py
m encodings.tis_620         C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\tis_620.py
m encodings.undefined       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\undefined.py
m encodings.unicode_escape  C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\unicode_escape.py
m encodings.unicode_internal C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\unicode_internal.py
m encodings.utf_16          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_16.py
m encodings.utf_16_be       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_16_be.py
m encodings.utf_16_le       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py
m encodings.utf_32          C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_32.py
m encodings.utf_32_be       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_32_be.py
m encodings.utf_32_le       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_32_le.py
m encodings.utf_7           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_7.py
m encodings.utf_8           C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_8.py
m encodings.utf_8_sig       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\utf_8_sig.py
m encodings.uu_codec        C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\uu_codec.py
m encodings.zlib_codec      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\encodings\zlib_codec.py
m enum                      C:\Python35\Lib\enum.py
m errno
m fnmatch                   C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\fnmatch.py
m functools                 C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\functools.py
m gc
m genericpath               C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\genericpath.py
m getopt                    C:\Python35\Lib\getopt.py
m gettext                   C:\Python35\Lib\gettext.py
m glob                      C:\Python35\Lib\glob.py
m gzip                      C:\Python35\Lib\gzip.py
m hashlib                   C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\hashlib.py
m heapq                     C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\heapq.py
P html                      C:\Python35\Lib\html\__init__.py
m html.entities             C:\Python35\Lib\html\entities.py
P http                      C:\Python35\Lib\http\__init__.py
m http.client               C:\Python35\Lib\http\client.py
m http.server               C:\Python35\Lib\http\server.py
m imp                       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\imp.py
P importlib                 C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py
m importlib._bootstrap      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py
m importlib._bootstrap_external C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py
m importlib.abc             C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\importlib\abc.py
m importlib.machinery       C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\importlib\machinery.py
m importlib.util            C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\importlib\util.py
m inspect                   C:\Python35\Lib\inspect.py
m io                        C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\io.py
m ipaddress                 C:\Python35\Lib\ipaddress.py
m itertools
m keyword                   C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\keyword.py
m linecache                 C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\linecache.py
m locale                    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\locale.py
P logging                   C:\Python35\Lib\logging\__init__.py
m lzma                      C:\Python35\Lib\lzma.py
m marshal
m math
m mimetypes                 C:\Python35\Lib\mimetypes.py
m msvcrt
m nt
m ntpath                    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\ntpath.py
m opcode                    C:\Python35\Lib\opcode.py
m operator                  C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\operator.py
m optparse                  C:\Python35\Lib\optparse.py
m os                        C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\os.py
m pdb                       C:\Python35\Lib\pdb.py
m pkgutil                   C:\Python35\Lib\pkgutil.py
m platform                  C:\Python35\Lib\platform.py
m plistlib                  C:\Python35\Lib\plistlib.py
m posixpath                 C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\posixpath.py
m pprint                    C:\Python35\Lib\pprint.py
m py_compile                C:\Python35\Lib\py_compile.py
m py_helloworld__init__     C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py
m py_helloworld__main__     py_helloWorld.py
m pydoc                     C:\Python35\Lib\pydoc.py
P pydoc_data                C:\Python35\Lib\pydoc_data\__init__.py
m pydoc_data.topics         C:\Python35\Lib\pydoc_data\topics.py
m pyexpat                   C:\Python35\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
m quopri                    C:\Python35\Lib\quopri.py
m random                    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\random.py
m re                        C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\re.py
m reprlib                   C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\reprlib.py
m select                    C:\Python35\DLLs\select.pyd
m selectors                 C:\Python35\Lib\selectors.py
m shlex                     C:\Python35\Lib\shlex.py
m shutil                    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\shutil.py
m signal                    C:\Python35\Lib\signal.py
m socket                    C:\Python35\Lib\socket.py
m socketserver              C:\Python35\Lib\socketserver.py
m sre_compile               C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\sre_compile.py
m sre_constants             C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\sre_constants.py
m sre_parse                 C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\sre_parse.py
m ssl                       C:\Python35\Lib\ssl.py
m stat                      C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\stat.py
m string                    C:\Python35\Lib\string.py
m stringprep                C:\Python35\Lib\stringprep.py
m struct                    C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\struct.py
m subprocess                C:\Python35\Lib\subprocess.py
m sys
m tarfile                   C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\tarfile.py
m tempfile                  C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\tempfile.py
m textwrap                  C:\Python35\Lib\textwrap.py
m threading                 C:\Python35\Lib\threading.py
m time
m token                     C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\token.py
m tokenize                  C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\tokenize.py
m traceback                 C:\Python35\Lib\traceback.py
m tty                       C:\Python35\Lib\tty.py
m types                     C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\types.py
m unicodedata               C:\Python35\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
P unittest                  C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\__init__.py
m unittest.case             C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\case.py
m unittest.loader           C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\loader.py
m unittest.main             C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\main.py
m unittest.result           C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\result.py
m unittest.runner           C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\runner.py
m unittest.signals          C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\signals.py
m unittest.suite            C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\suite.py
m unittest.util             C:\Python35\Lib\unittest\util.py
P urllib                    C:\Python35\Lib\urllib\__init__.py
m urllib.parse              C:\Python35\Lib\urllib\parse.py
m uu                        C:\Python35\Lib\uu.py
m warnings                  C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\warnings.py
m weakref                   C:\AD-install\virtualenvs\cx_freeze_env\lib\weakref.py
m webbrowser                C:\Python35\Lib\webbrowser.py
m winreg
P xml                       C:\Python35\Lib\xml\__init__.py
P xml.parsers               C:\Python35\Lib\xml\parsers\__init__.py
m xml.parsers.expat         C:\Python35\Lib\xml\parsers\expat.py
m zipfile                   C:\Python35\Lib\zipfile.py
m zipimport
m zlib

Missing modules:
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib, importlib.abc
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? _winreg imported from platform
? ce imported from os
? grp imported from shutil, tarfile
? java.lang imported from platform
? org.python.core imported from copy
? os.path imported from os, pkgutil, py_compile, unittest, unittest.util
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from http.server, posixpath, shutil, tarfile, webbrowser
? termios imported from tty
? vms_lib imported from platform
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.

copying C:\Python35\DLLs\_bz2.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\_bz2.pyd
copying C:\Python35\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\_hashlib.pyd
copying C:\Python35\DLLs\_lzma.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\_lzma.pyd
copying C:\Python35\DLLs\_socket.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\_socket.pyd
copying C:\Python35\DLLs\_ssl.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\_ssl.pyd
copying C:\Python35\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\pyexpat.pyd
copying C:\Python35\DLLs\select.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\select.pyd
copying C:\Python35\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.5\libs\unicodedata.pyd
```

Then calling the built exe (either in or out of the virtualenv) from the command line gives:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00001cec (most recent call first):
```

I'm running Python 3.5 (32-bit version) on Windows 10 on a 64-bit machine.  I'm running in a virtualenv with the following:

```
appdirs (1.4.3) 
cx-Freeze (5.0.1) 
et-xmlfile (1.0.1) 
jdcal (1.3)    
numpy (1.12.1+mkl) 
opencv-python (3.2.0+contrib) 
openpyxl (2.4.7)    
packaging (16.8) 
pip (9.0.1) 
pyparsing (2.2.0) 
setuptools (35.0.2)    
six (1.10.0) 
wheel (0.29.0)
```

What am I doing wrong?  I've searched for quite a while and none of the forums or tutorials address this issue (that I've found so far).

Comment: For what it's worth, I was trying cx_Freeze because py2exe does not have a wheel precompiled for Windows for Python 3.5.  Since then I've tried PyInstaller and it's been working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone:

If you copy the exe, dll, etc files from the build\exe.win32-3.5 folder to another location *without including subfolders*, you are liable to get the exact same error message.